# Deploying VoltRb app on Heroku with persistence from MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, heroku, voltrb

I'm trying to get a new/blank volt (0.9.5) app into production on Heroku following the instructions on the Volt docs page.

The application deploys successfully until I try and add the Mongo database.

The below creates a new MongoLab database and sets a connection URI to the MONGOLAB_URI variable.

```
 $ heroku addons:create mongolab
```

I thought all I had to do was copy the below into my **config/app.rb** file and replace the 'MONGOHQ_URL' with 'MONGOLAB_URI'.

```
config.db_driver = 'mongo'
config.db_name = (config.app_name + '_' + Volt.env.to_s)

if ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'].present?
  config.db_uri = ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] # you will have to set this on heroku
else
  config.db_host = 'localhost'
  config.db_port = 27017
end
```

But this is resulting in an application error and the log is showing the below...

```
[ERROR] Error adding listener: #<Mongo::AuthenticationError: Failed to authenticate user
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Some other users suggested that the issue was to do with an outdated version of the volt-mongo gem which was, "using an old version of the Mongo Ruby driver." I have since upgraded to the latest version (currently 0.1.4) and everything seems to be working ok with the database.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but you should be able to run heroku config to see what ENV's are set for the dyno.  Does that show the ENV?

Comment: Yes, running `$ heroku config` shows MONGOLAB_URI set. It was auto-generated by Heroku and matches the format on the MongoLab page,

`mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds######.mongolab.com:#####/<Database>`

I also tried making my own DB at MongoLab and setting MONGOLAB_URI myself and got the same result. The full error message actually does reference my user credentials.

Have been trying to switch from thin to puma but ran into the issue I mentioned on gitter so I can't see if that would work :(

Comment: Apologies @Ryan, as well as MONGOLAB_URI, RACK_ENV: production for `$ heroku config`

Comment: Try updating the volt-mongo version for the app:  bundle update volt-mongo  Let me know if that works.  Thanks!